# RSpec implict subject seems to fail, explicit subject works

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a simple test that it seems to have a different behavior depending on whether I use an explicit subject or not.

```
context "successful validation" do
  subject(:invitation) {invitations(:emmet_invite)}
  after do
    invitation.send_voucher
  end
  it "calls hotel_booked?" do
    invitation.should_receive(:hotel_booked?).and_return(true) #works
  end

  it {should_receive(:hotel_booked?).and_return(true)} #fails
end
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: It took me a long time to figure out what you were trying to test here, because you have buried the main action of the test inside an "after" block. It's probably a matter of taste, but I don't think the two or three lines you gain by doing that are worth it at this case.

Comment: I see your point. I just decided to give it a try this way since the one-liners fit better with the other tests in the code (made by other devs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this github issue in rspec-mocks: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/148

Quote:

> Implicit subject was added to support one line expectations, but I don't believe it was ever intended for use with mock expectations. For a mock expectation to make any sense, there has to be some code in the example after it was set, so it doesn't really make sense to use for one liners.

So basically, you can't use `should_receive` with an implicit subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subject` to get at the implicit subject:

```
it { subject.should_receive(:hotel_booked?).and_return(true) }
```

though this is not as easy to read as your explicit example.